# How can I find data between date range in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'm looking for find elements when date is between two date ? like this for exemple :

```
async function getTop() {
    let songDB = await Song.find({
        daterating: new date(2020-12-17T03:24:00) < dateRating < new Date()
    }).sort('rating');
    console.log(songDB)
    return songDB;
}
```

How it's possible in mongoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
let songDB = await Song.find(
    {
        daterating: {$gte: new date("2020-12-17T03:24:00"), $lte: new Date()}
    }).sort('rating');
```

Comment: this is return only one entry in database. is it normal ?

Comment: `find` returns an array of results. if only one returns then it means you only have one matching document to the query in your database

Comment: ok thank you verry much !

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$gte` & `$lt` for start and end dates. Assuming **daterating** is a field in your mongoose schema holding the date.

Try something like the following:

```
await Song.find({
  daterating: {
    $gte: new Date(2020-12-17T03:24:00),
    $lte: new Date.now()
  }
}).sort('rating');
```

Please be aware this is untested.